# Did you know there's grants for running an Ethereum node?

Tags: discussion

I saw this question [Does any one have the archive node data?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151206/does-any-one-have-the-archive-node-data)

Instead of just letting them know an option is to apply for a grant, I thought it could help others more broadly by posting here.  There's a chance that some will be upset at this post, and if so it will be a learning lesson.

https://esp.ethereum.foundation/run-a-node-grants

Starting on June 7, 2023, we will begin to accept proposals.

**Deadline: June 20, 2023**

- The Ethereum Foundation is launching a new funding round to encourage experimentation and development with Ethereum nodes.
- Running a node on Ethereum provides increased security, access, control, and flexibility and allows you to participate in and contribute to the Ethereum network actively.
- Nodes are a critical element of Ethereum, and we are looking for creative proposals from a diverse range of users looking to run a node. You may be based in a different geographical region; perhaps you want your university to use a node for research purposes - surprise us with your application.
- Selected applicants will receive either a Dappnode sent directly to you or a fixed allocated sum to reimburse the cost of the hardware.